# Точки пересечения эллипса и прямой

Tags: java, алгоритм, gui, математика, swing

Собственно цель в названии вопроса. У меня имеются координаты верхнего левого угла и нижнего правого угла ограничивающего прямоугольника для эллипса (другими словами эллипс вписан в этот прямоугольник). Также, имеются две точки прямой. Координатная система - левый верхний угол окна 0;0, y направлена вниз, x направлена вправо. Как пытался решить:

Вот уравнение эллипса с центром `x0;y0` (мой случай):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот уравнение прямой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Взял уравнение эллипса и прямой, упростил, выразил из них X. Через дискриминант получаю:

- если `D < 0` - корней нет, прямая не пересекает эллипс;
- если `D == 0` - корень один, прямая является касательной к эллипсу (могу быть не прав);
- если `D > 0` - корней два, как раз точки пересечения прямой эллипса.

И еще один исключительный случай: если у прямой `x2 - x1` очень близко к нулю, то формула меняется, и через дискриминант мы уже выражаем `y`, а `x` будет равен `x1 || x2` (так как они совпадают, в моем случае координаты приходят целочисленные).
Я проверил этот способ, он отлично работает с эллипсом который является окружностью. Однако, как только у эллипса `a != b` - алгоритм ошибается, и я никак не могу найти проблему. Ниже прикладываю подробный код (специально расписал длиннее, чтобы было легче найти проблему), в котором заложен вышеописанный алгоритм + исключительной случай, когда `x2 - x1` очень близко к нулю:

```
private void calculatePointsIntersectBlock(Rectangle rect, Point pt1, Point pt2){
        Rectangle rectCoordinate = new Rectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.x+ rect.width, rect.y+ rect.height);// координаты эллипса
        double _a = rect.width / 2.0; // полуось эллипса a
        double _b = rect.height / 2.0; // полуось эллипса b
        double x0 = (rectCoordinate.x + rectCoordinate.width) /2.0; // x центр эллипса
        double y0 = (rectCoordinate.y + rectCoordinate.height) /2.0; // y центр эллипса
        // уравнение прямой
        double k = (pt2.y - pt1.y) / (double)(pt2.x - pt1.x);
        double b = pt1.y - k * pt1.x;
        // уравнение эллипса
        double v = (_a*_a)*(_b*_b);
        double s = b - y0;
        // собранное квадратное уравнение
        double A = -1;
        double B = -1;
        double C = -1;
        if(pt2.x - pt1.x != 0) {
            A = (_a * _a) + (_b * _b) * (k * k);
            B = 2 * ((_a * _a) * k * s - (_b * _b) * x0);
            C = (_a * _a) * (x0 * x0) + (_b * _b) * (s * s) - v;
        }else{ // исключительная ситуация x2 - x1 близко к нулю
            double w = (1 - (Math.pow(pt1.x - x0, 2) / (_a*_a))) * (_b*_b);
            A = 1;
            B = -2 * y0;
            C = (y0 * y0) - w;
        }
        // решаем и выводим два корня
        double D = (B * B) - 4*A*C;
        // подставляем и находим x и y
        if(pt2.x - pt1.x != 0) {
            // одна точка пересечения
            if (D < 0) {
                return; // точек пересечения нет
            } else if (D == 0) {
                double x1 = (-B * 2) / (2 * A);
                Point single = new Point((int) x1, (int) (k * x1 + b)); // единственная точка
            } else {
                // две точки
                double x1 = (-B - Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * A);
                double x2 = (-B + Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * A);
                double y1 = k * x1 + b;
                double y2 = k * x2 + b;
                Point first = new Point((int) x1, (int) y1); // первая точка
                Point second = new Point((int) x2, (int) y2); // вторая точка
            }
        }else{ // исключительная ситуация x2 - x1 близко к нулю
            if (D < 0) {
                return; // точек пересечения нет
            } else if (D == 0) {
                // одна точка
                double y1 = (-B * 2) / (2 * A);
                Point single = new Point((int) 0, (int) y1); // единственная точка
            } else {
                // две точки
                double y1 = (-B - Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * A);
                double y2 = (-B + Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * A);
                double x1 = pt1.x;
                double x2 = pt1.x;
                Point first = new Point((int) x1, (int) y1); // первая точка
                Point second = new Point((int) x2, (int) y2); // вторая точка
            }
        }
    }
```

Помогите найти ошибку. Проверял на бумаге, но никак не могу найти, вроде бы всё сходится.

Comment: `A = (_a * _a) + (_b * _b) * (k * k);` -> `A = (_b * _b) + (_a * _a) * (k * k);`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy к сожалению не помогло, по сути таже самая проблема с эллипсами. Все время возвращается D < 0

Comment: Это только первая ошибка. :)

Comment: `double x0 = (rectCoordinate.x + rectCoordinate.width) /2.0;` -> `double x0 = rectCoordinate.x + rectCoordinate.width /2.0;`

Comment: Округление в конце добавляет ошибок.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил все Ваши правки - не помогло, но перестало работать с окружностью :) По поводу округления - оно же происходит после расчетов, а у нас уже D < 0, то есть в тот блок мы даже не заходим

Comment: `double y0 = rectCoordinate.y + rectCoordinate.height / 2.0;` тоже поправили?

Comment: `C = (_a * _a) * (x0 * x0) + (_b * _b) * (s * s) - v;` -> `C = (_b * _b) * (x0 * x0) + (_a * _a) * (s * s) - v;`

Comment: Теперь, кажется, всё.

Comment: Сделайте код в вопросе рабочим. Он даже не компилируется. Не хорошо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy прошу прощения, не заметил. Были еще расчеты, поэтому остались хвосты...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy поведение изменилось, но стало похуже. Иногда пролетает с окружность., иногда нет. С эллипсом похожая ситуация, но пересечение , такое ощущение, вычисляется по bbox, а не по окружности.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127429/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and-range).

Answer (score 3):

**Ошибки**

Я буду использовать формат `diff`. Центр эллипса вычислен с ошибкой:

```
<         double x0 = (rectCoordinate.x + rectCoordinate.width) /2.0; // x центр эллипса
<         double y0 = (rectCoordinate.y + rectCoordinate.height) /2.0; // y центр эллипса
---
>         double x0 = rectCoordinate.x + rectCoordinate.width / 2.0; // x центр эллипса
>         double y0 = rectCoordinate.y + rectCoordinate.height / 2.0; // y центр эллипса
```

В коэффициентах `A` и `C` перепутаны полуоси эллипса:

```
<             A = (_a * _a) + (_b * _b) * (k * k);
---
>             A = (_b * _b) + (_a * _a) * (k * k);

<             C = (_a * _a) * (x0 * x0) + (_b * _b) * (s * s) - v;
---
>             C = (_b * _b) * (x0 * x0) + (_a * _a) * (s * s) - v;
```

После исправления ошибок программа вычисляет точки пересечения, но чтобы убедится в этом без использования отладчика, нужно устранить ...

**Недостатки**

Функция ничего не возвращает, проверить её можно только в отладчике. Это возможно, но долго и муторно. Исправим возвращаемое значение функции:

```
<     private void calculatePointsIntersectBlock(Rectangle rect, Point pt1, Point pt2){
---
>     public static DPoint[] calculatePointsIntersectBlock(Rectangle rect, Point pt1, Point pt2) {
```

`DPoint` - точка с координатами типа `double`. Типом `Point` я пользоваться не хочу, он целочисленный, а мне нужны неокруглённые значения для проверки.

Возвращаемые значения будут такими:

```
return new DPoint[] {}; // точек пересечения нет
...
return new DPoint[] {single};  // единственная точка
...
return new DPoint[] {first, second}; // пара точек
```

Теперь можно написать тесты (14 штук достаточно чтобы проверить все случаи) и убедится что исправленный код работает как требуется.

**Комментарий**

Ошибки из первого пункта возникли так как код сложный, а его обоснования перед глазами нет. В этом случае необходим длинный пошаговый комментарий который объясняет как уравнения относятся к параметрам метода, как уравнения разрешаются и как строится ответ.

**Упрощение кода**

Код сложный: перевод параметров функции в величины, относящиеся к задаче, построение квадратного уравнения, решение уравнения, восстановление точек пересечения. Всё нужно разбить на функции, которые можно протестировать отдельно.

**Уравнение прямой**

Уравнение прямой вида `y = kx + b` как правило бесполезно в программировании. Во-первых, оно не годится для вертикальных прямых. Во-вторых, коэффициент `k` вычисляется как отношение `(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`. Почему это не хорошо - ниже.

Введите параметр `t`:

> ```
> x = x1 + t(x2 - x1)
> y = y1 + t(y2 - y1)
> ```

Можно проверить что система уравнений выше задаёт прямую проходящую через точки `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)`. Деления нет, специальных случаев нет. Эту систему уравнений следует подставить в уравнение эллипса, решить относительно `t`, по его значениям восстановить точки на прямой.

**Код**

Интерфейс подогнан под теорию, решение квадратного уравнения вынесено в отдельный метод, в комментариях изложена теория:

```
public static DPoint[] intersectEllipseLine(
    double x0, // центр эллипса (x)
    double y0, // центр эллипса (y)
    double a , // горизонтальная полуось эллипса
    double b , // вертикальная полуось эллипса
    double x1, // первая точка определяющая прямую (x)
    double y1, // первая точка определяющая прямую (y)
    double x2, // вторая точка определяющая прямую (x)
    double y2  // вторая точка определяющая прямую (y)
) {
    // параметрическое (от t) уравнение прямой
    // x = (x2 - x1)t + x1
    // y = (y2 - y1)t + y1
    //
    // уравнение эллипса
    // (x - x0)^2 / a^2 + (y - y0)^2 / b^2 = 1
    // <->
    // b^2 (x - x0)^2 + a^2 (y - y0)^2 = a^2 b^2
    //
    // подставляем прямую в эллипс
    // b^2 ((x2 - x1)t + x1 - x0)^2 + a^2 ((y2 - y1)t + y1 - y0)^2 = a^2 b^2
    // <-> (x21 := x2 - x1, y21 := y2 - y1, x10 := x1 - x0, y10 := y1 - y0)
    // b^2 (x21 t + x10)^2 + a^2 (y21 t + y10)^2 = a^2 b^2
    // <->
    // (b^2 x21^2 + a^2 y21^2) t^2 + 
    // 2(b^2 x21 x10 + aa^2 y21 y10) t + 
    // (b^2 x10^2 + a^2 y10^2 - a^2 b^2) = 0

    final double x21 = x2 - x1;
    final double y21 = y2 - y1;

    final double x10 = x1 - x0;
    final double y10 = y1 - y0;

    final double a2 = a * a;
    final double b2 = b * b;

    final double t[] = solveQuadraticEquation(
        b2 * x21 * x21 + a2 * y21 * y21,
        2 * (b2 * x21 * x10 + a2 * y21 * y10),
        b2 * x10 * x10 + a2 * y10 * y10 - a2 * b2
    );

    // восстанавливаем точки пересечения

    final DPoint p[] = new DPoint[t.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; ++i) {
        p[i] = new DPoint(
            t[i] * (x2 - x1) + x1,
            t[i] * (y2 - y1) + y1
        );
    }
    return p;
}
```